# SQL Server Database Diagram Vanished

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database on SQL server 2008 express with aprox 30 tables and many more relationships than that.  I had a database diagram showing all the relationships between the tables which was very useful.  However it has completely vanished.  All the data and tables is there, but the diagram has simply vanished.  This has happened once before, although at a much earlier stage of the database' development, so I simply redesigned the diagram.  But I am loathed to do so again.

Has anyone any clues whatsoever as to how this can happen?

Comment: Maybe someone restored an old backup over the top! I've seen this happen before after I deployed a DB - one of the DBA's restored a backup over the database seemingly forgetting about the swathes of sprocs and config data in the new deploy...!

Comment: IMHO, you can check the transaction logs to see when it happened and through which user.

Comment: I had a script which removed the data from all tables so that I could test my application, and keep reseting (blanking) the database.  Apparently this 'script' also deletes diagrams :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had run a script to clear the test data from the tables, which it seems also deletes all system diagrams - so it was self inflicted :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this (after taking a backup):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.sysdiagrams ON
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.sysdiagrams (name, principal_id, diagram_id, version, definition)
SELECT name, principal_id, diagram_id, version, definition
FROM schema1.sysdiagrams
GO
```